# How do I format a PHP include() absolute (rather than relative) path?

Tags: php, path, include

On various pages throughout my PHP web site and in various nested directories I want to include a specific file at a path relative to the root.

What single command can I put on both of these pages...

```
http://www.example.com/pageone.php
```

```
http://www.example.com/somedirectory/pagetwo.php
```

...to include this page:

```
http://www.example.com/includes/analytics.php
```

This does not work:

```
<?php include('/includes/analytics.php'); ?>
```

Does it matter that this is hosted in IIS on Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you give include() or require() (or the *_once versions) an absolute pathname, that file will be included. An absolute pathname starts with a "/" on unix, and with a drive letter and colon on Windows.

If you give a relative path (any other path), PHP will search the directories in the configuration value "include_path" in order, until a match is found or there are no more directories to search.

So, in short, to include an absolute filename, give an absolute filename. See also the function [realpath()](http://www.php.net/realpath).

If you want to set your own include "root", have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344419/how-do-i-set-an-absolute-include-path-in-php) (specifically my answer of course :-)

Comment: Hi, i have a question about php include part. Can you check my bounty question please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47793007/included-php-files-wont-work-after-moved-files-subfolder/47853654#47853654

Answer (score 26):

You can just use `include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/includes/analytics.php";`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on streamline.net servers either... Think they're Linux?

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks a bunch. I wish I could upvote this multiple times.

Answer (score 9):

From the perspective of PHP root is the top of the file system on the web server, not the root from the perspective of the web browser.

Most people do one of the below.

Define a constant, in a global configuration file, and use that in each call to require/include.

Or they use code like this.

```
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/config.php');
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/lib/Database.php');
```

Using the environmental variables may be dangerous in some cases and be the source of security issues.

Comment: Could you describe (or link to) the vulnerabilities this might expose?

Comment: @Justin, If we assume, that PHP, your web server, and the configuration is bug free, then this could not be abused.  If like in the real world, you know there are bugs and miss-configurations.  Be defensive, and don't trust external input.  I imagine a scenario, in a shared-server setup, where something was buggy or got miss-configured, and it resulted the PHP being forced to include harmful code.  I am a bit paranoid about trying to avoid invalid code getting executed by scripts I have authored.

Comment: I was just trying to suggest, that before you include something using a variable in the path, you should verify that variable cannot be modified to be invalid.

Comment: Makes sense. Are you aware of any performance or security reasons to use `dirname(__FILE__)` vs. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`?

Comment: The `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable is supplied by the web server.  As mentioned in one of the other answers, this doesn't show up if you are using IIS, so I am not sure you can trust that as a cross-platform.  The `__FILE__` variable is provided by the PHP interpreter.  dirname() is a built in function in PHP.  If I am running PHP, I basically have to trust the PHP internal stuff isn't broken.

Answer (score 8):

As @Stefan Mai says, PHP doesn't have a "root" path but you can define one quite easily - most sites have a page that's included every time (e.g. configuration file), to which you can add:

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

Then use include ROOT . '/includes/analytics.php';

Something that's also quite useful is the auto_prepend directive, which you can use in .htaccess on apache - not sure about setting it up on IIS (although you can have a global one in the PHP ini).

Comment: of COURSE php has a root. It's the filesystem root!

Answer (score 5):

I combined the above suggestions and came up with this.

In my `config.php` file, I define ROOT as:

`define('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);`

Then I use it in my succeding files:

`include_once(ROOT."/someFile.php");`

`include_once(ROOT."/includes/someFile.php");`

Answer (score 1):

Use .. to go up a directory.  So in pageone.php

```
include 'includes/analytics.php';
```

in pagetwo.php

```
include '../includes/analytics.php';
```

There's no notion of "root" as you're referring to in PHP as far as I know, though you could define it if you wanted.  Best of luck!

Comment: There's no way to use an absolute path?

Comment: You can use an absolute path like "c:/includes/analytics.php" or "/home/iamnafets/includes/analytics.php", but PHP files aren't part of a "project" or "virtual directory" like ASP pages are.

Comment: I wasn't specific enough.  I want a single command that will work from either page.

Comment: You can change what directories PHP will search with the include_path directive. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344419/how-do-i-set-an-absolute-include-path-in-php

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
<?php include('c:/inetpub/example.com/includes/analytics.php'); ?>
```

I'll have to make the `c:/inetpub/example.com/` part some kind of global variable so it's somewhat portable from server to server.

Comment: This will cause problems when you move your site to another server.

Answer (score 0):

The tilde is interpreted as a special character by the shell, so using it inside PHP code won't work regardless of OS.

If you're trying to access something relative to a user home directory you could try `getenv()` - I'm pretty sure Windows sets an environment variable equivalent to `$HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I found is:

```
<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\\Your\\Site\\Path.php' ?>
```

The \\ is necesary when you have some special character that could be escaped (i.e. \n), so that \\ is \ on the string.

Because you are in windows, you have to use \ instead of /