# Alternative ways to structure my website layout and content loading

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

A while ago I built a fan site for a PC game, and I believe that it could be set up better. Basically, right now all of my pages share a common header and footer, and the only real difference between pages is the content loaded into a main table cell.

Currently, I am trying to make 'clean' URLs by having each page in its own directory with an index.php file.

For example, my 'About' page is located in /about/index.php, but it can be accessed by just going to /about

Here is how the index.php looks inside of the 'about' directory:

```
<?php include '/home/content/69/7232369/html/loco_header.html' ?>
<tr><td>
    <table class="mainpagetable">
<tr>
    <td class="maincontent">
        <table class="contenttable" >
            <tr><td><div class="contenttop"><span class="newheader">About</span></div>
            <div class="contentmiddle" id="contentmiddle">
            <table class="newcontent">
            <tr><td>
            <br>
            <?php include 'about.html'; ?>
        </td></tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="contentbottom"></div></td></tr>

</table>

            </td>
    <td class="gap">

    &nbsp;</td>
<?php include '/home/content/69/7232369/html/site_footer.html' ?>
```

So basically, I created the entire layout in HTML, separating the parts of the site by using tables within tables. I have a PHP include for the header, the page content, and the footer. All of my pages look like this, and it seemed like a good approach at first, however I recently switched to a different host and when I copied everything over, none of the includes for the headers/footers worked because of the different path to the root directory:

```
<?php include '/home/content/69/7232369/html/loco_header.html' ?>
```

Which was a pain to go through 100+ php files and change the header/footer include on each of them one by one. It was then that I realized I am probably doing something wrong.

**So my questions are:**

**1)** Is there  function in PHP that returns the root directory for your website, so that I could do something like  include $root . "/header.html"  ?

**2)** My method for creating clean URLs creates quite a bit of extra directories and files. Is there a different recommended approach that I can take which would run smooth and generate less files (while still being search engine friendly)?

**3)** Is there more efficient/more manageable approach for loading the content into the center of my page, that would also work nicely with a method for having clean URLs (see question #2)? AJAX comes to mind, however I would like there to be an actual URL link to each content page, rather than having everything loaded dynamically in the middle of my home page without the URL changing. I honestly don't know if there is a good solution to this.

**4)** Is it considered poor practice to use tables within tables for structuring my layout? As you can see, I am splitting up my HTML code in the middle of table tags and placing it in 3 different files (header, index, footer) to structure my site. This seems bad to me.

If it helps to clarify the structure of my pages, here is a link to a page on my site: http://locohq.com/about/

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: absolutely it is a poor practise to use tables for controlling the presentation part of the web-site, I would recommend you to use the html for structuring, CSS for the presentation and javascript ( you can use advanced framwork like Ajax, JQuery) for the operation part. You can also refer Google for designing and best practice

Comment: More style: [Cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html) - Don't concentrate on your URLs, but instead improve the HTML/CSS side of your site.

Comment: I suppose that replacing my tables with DIVs and then use CSS to position them the same way that they are now would be a good start. I just don't know how I should load content into the center of my page. This website is retired, however I would like to use it as practice before I build another one so that I have a better understanding of good design practices. Perhaps I could do something like locohq.com/page?=about, then use javascript to read that and dynamically load the 'about.html' into the content div?

Comment: Also, would I be able to set up the .htaccess file in such a way so that going locohq.com/about will load locohq.com/page?=about, and all of my pages in that way instead? Or is that done using some other method?

Comment: @Sandoichi: have you considered using a framework like Zend or CakePHP instead? Seems like they solve a lot of your problems easily without you having to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing all of my tables and replacing them with  elements and properly structuring using CSS.

For loading my content, I just made a main index page with a "content" container in the center of it. Within that container, I put a simple block of PHP code:

```
<?php 
        if(isset($_GET["content"])){
            $file = $_GET["content"] . ".php";
            if (file_exists($file))
                include($file); 
            else
                echo "Cannot find page <b>" . $_GET["content"] . "</b>";
        }
        else
            echo "No content loaded";
?>
```

Basically I load content into my page by linking to main.php?content=page and the code from whatever the content is gets loaded into the container.

To get around the ugly URL, I used mod_rewrite and put this into my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ pages/main.php?content=$1
```

So if I entered a URL as **www.example.com/about**   it would load **www.example.com/pages/main.php?content=about**    and then the code inside of the file **/pages/about.php** would get loaded into my content container. If the user tries to go to a page that doesn't exist, it will load the main page and inside of the content container, it will display a message that the page they are looking for doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your includes can be relative rather than absolute.

```
<?php include 'site_footer.html'; ?>
```

The above would probably work for you.

Comment: The header and footer are only located in the root directory for my website. I made changes to them quite a bit, and if they were in every directory then it would be quite tedious to update them in 100 different folders. It seems like there should be a better method to achieve this.

Comment: @Sandoichi - you can place these in something like an 'includes' folder, then reference that: `<?php include '/includes/site_footer.html'; ?>`  See here for a better explanation: http://buildinternet.com/2009/12/using-the-php-include-function-to-template-faster/

Comment: @motoxer4533 That is a relative path though right? So I would have to create an 'includes' folder in each directory. The way my site is set up now, each page has its own directory (/about, /items, /modes, /equipment, /movies, etc) so my issue was that I didn't want a header/footer file in each directory because I would have to replace each one every time I made a small change. This was part of my overall problem. That is why I was hoping to find a function to return the path to my root directory. But perhaps nothing like this exists.

Comment: / includes/ is absolute. Something like ../includes/ is relative.

Comment: Have a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344823/how-do-i-format-a-php-include-absolute-rather-than-relative-path

Comment: @motoxer4533 Thanks for that link. I tried out $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and it works perfectly for including my files.

Comment: @Derek yeah, I understand that part. I was just hung up on how to get to the root directory, since my pages are all within at least 1 level of sub-directories. I did get ("../includes/header.php") to work for the ones that were only 1 directory deep, but for the others I needed something different. Perhaps my directory layout will change once I figure out a better method to clean my URLs, and I will just be able to use relative paths then. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe what your looking for may be:

```
    <?php 
        $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    ?>
```

but if not you can see everything in the `$_SERVER` array you have to work with by executing:

```
    <?php
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_SERVER);
    ?>
```

Good luck, hopefully this is what you were looking for... I am a bit caffeine deprived today!

P.S I found this question as I'm trying to look for the most efficient way to load content into a layout, will update later with what I find!

Comment: Check out the answer I wrote for how I solved loading content into my site. It has been working very well and was easy to implement.