# how to add absolute path with php include

Tags: php, include-path

I am adding a absolute path with the php include.

$path ="/";

```
instead of include('../connect.php');

i want to include like include($path.'connect.php');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344823/how-do-i-format-a-php-include-absolute-rather-than-relative-path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using any framework, then follow that, otherwise you can do following:

```
$path = __DIR__;
include($path . '/connect.php'); // change this to match path
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using something simular then that. I am using a p value out of the link to get my page. 
I pulled out the snippet you are refering too here

```
$pages_dir = 'inc/content';
include($pages_dir.'/'.$p.'.inc.php');
```