# site root relative path confusion in php

Tags: php, directory, relative-path

I'm trying to upload images to server, create a thumbnail from the uploaded image, and save the relative paths to mysql database . . . . The image path is

```
     /mysite/images/
```

from my site root (which is wamp/www/mysite/images in my local testing environment)

Now, I'm performing a directory check  with

```
   if(!is_dir($path) && !is_writable($path)){
    throw new Exception ("$path is not valid .. ");
    }
```

where path is /mysite/images/ , thinking that initial '/' will denote the root.

But, the script was throwing an exception saying invalid path name, and my

```
     move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path.$filename)
```

too was not working.

**PS:** the path mysite/images/ also throws an error and the file is not moved

Now, I have worked around by appending document root manually to path name for both directory checks and move file , which is now looking like

```
      if(!is_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path) && !is_writable($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path)){
    throw new Exception ("$path is not valid .. ");
    }

      move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$path.$filename)
```

I also changed the path to

```
    mysite/images/
```

removing the initial slash intended for site root. This is **working perfectly**.

But, I cannot understand why directory check and move uploaded file snippets are not taking site root relative links.

Any ideas is appreciated.

Comment: The [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function might be useful here

Comment: Also, related: this answer and the one below it - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4426192/1470907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the path representation.

In linux /mysite  will try to access the directory in the root level of file system. Windows this might not create an error. for is_file() kind of API's it should the absolute path and not relative ones.

Answer (score 1):

Your website path is not `wamp/www/mysite/images`.

You are using a web server, you cant access the drive like: c:/wamp ....

Once online, how will you access your files? Linux does not have c:/ ...

Your website path is: `http://localhost/mysite/`

Your image path is: `http://localhost/mysite/images` or `./images` if your code is correctly written.

so, do this:

```
define('ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

include_once(ROOT."/mycfgfile.php");
```

or

```
include_once(ROOT."/includes/mycfgfile.php");
```

Comment: do I have to check for directory permissions using ROOT.$path always?

Comment: on my webserver, i have set manually the folder permissions; and i dont check these settings every time i write a image in that folder; the script can write in that folder because is a request from the localhost; a visitor can not write in that folder, because the request does not come from localhost; on my server, if the image type is jpeg, write it, if not, drop it

Comment: even if my website is online at www.example.com, the request comes from localhost, because the apache web server is on that machine