# How PHP require file logic works?

Tags: php, include-path

File tree;

- boot.php
- panel/index.php
- panel/inc/start.php
- panel/inc/functions.php

Process:

- index.php; requires 'inc/start.php'
- start.php; requires '../boot.php' and 'functions.php'
- (require_once 'x.php' used)

Everything works when index.php called. Why i don't have to use ../../boot.php instead of ../boot.php?
If relative folder is /panel, then require 'functions.php' should fail. If it is /panel/inc, require '../boot.php' should fail. But eveything works. How?

Note: I know i should use absolute folder to include files. I am just trying to understand how this example works.

Comment: because you require everything from within index.php.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2418473/161052, http://stackoverflow.com/q/344823/161052

Comment: Read the documentation first.

Comment: I don't think the absolute path is a good idea, because you need to change it when moving a project from a developing environment to a productional one (eg. webhosting).

Comment: That's what `__DIR__` macro is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the PHP manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

> If a path is defined — whether absolute (starting with a drive letter
>   or \ on Windows, or / on Unix/Linux systems) or relative to the
>   current directory (starting with . or ..)

When PHP includes / requires a file, it looks for a path relative to the current file position.

Comment: I was going to link to the manual also, you beat me to it. =)

Comment: Actually the part says "finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing" answered my question. Because i was thinking it takes only one directory to check as relative. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your index.php file, while processing, will include inc/start.php. So your index.php will look like

```
<?php 
 //inc/start.php file content here
 //require '../boot.php';
```

So the boot.php will be included like it including from index.php itself