# How to place calls to divs globally

Tags: php, html, architecture

I have some divs that I want to display under some specific conditions in every page. I put the calls to them in the footer like this:

```
<div id="loginpopup" style="display: none;">
<?php
include '/auth/login_form.php';
?>
</div>

<div id="createprofilepopup" style="display: none;">
<?php
include '/auth/create_profile_form.php';
?>
</div>

<?php
// Show div that spins when something is happening
include '/divs/loading.php';
?>
```

but the urls seem to be mis-pointed. And if I fix the urls on any page, pages in other directory  paths will be mispointed.  What is the correct way to organize this sort of thing across a site?

Thanks!

By tje way if you want to take a look, the currently broken site is http://www.problemio.com

Comment: view the absolute and relative path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344419/how-do-i-set-an-absolute-include-path-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you include the files it loads them from an absolute path (in Linux the root directory). If you want to load them relative to the current script just don't add the leading slash:

```
include 'auth/login_form.php';
```

Comment: yeah, but I actually wanted it to work from an absolute path from the root.  The way you suggest will only work from one directory, but any other directory the path breaks.

Comment: That's why you usually define a constant like APPLICATION_PATH (and use it like *include APPLICATION_PATH . 'auth/login_form.php';*)
which is the absolute path of the folder you are using to include files. Root folder (/) with the include means the operating systems root folder - which is probably not what you want.