# Fatal Error: Call to undefined function working then failing again?

Tags: php, mysql, fatal-error

I am using PHP Version 5.4.7.

Initially, I was faced with a `Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Connect() in C:\htdocs\mods\conn.php on line 15` when trying to access the home page of my custom php website which I have not accessed for some time and have updated my php version since.

After some investigation, I changed the following line in `conn.php`

```
include_once ("DB.php");
```

to

```
include_once ("mods/DB.php");
```

Now for some reason, that I am unaware, the page is working well and displaying with no errors.
Until trying to use the audit trail module, at which point the initial error comes back.

`Fatal error:  Call to undefined function Connect() in C:\htdocs\mods\conn.php on line 15`

back again.

The url is: `http://project/audit/monthly.php?year=2014&month=11`

So I thought the error is in `monthly.php` but now I think it must be that it must be a problem with a reference. So I looked at `monthly.php` and found that it uses a number of files, most notably:

```
require_once 'header.php';
```

header uses `conn.php` with a:

```
require_once ("mods/conn.php");
```

I am unsure how to continue here as the spelling of the conn.php and case is correct. It also worked previously.

**Conn.php**

```
//include_once ("DB.php");
include_once ("mods/DB.php");
include_once ("date.php");
include_once ("forms.php");
include_once ("sess.php");
include_once ("utilities.php");

//--- define user types

ConnectToDB ("localhost", None, "audit", "abc", "pass");

// Zend Auto loader....
**> NOT ADDED**

$db = Zend_Db::factory("PDO_MYSQL", array
(
    "host"      => 'localhost',
    "username"  => 'abc',
    "password"  => 'pass',
    "dbname"    => 'audit'
));

?>
```

**DB.php**

```
<?php
function Connect ($Host, $Port, $DBName, $User, $Password) {

    **A custom connect function**

}
?>
```

Comment: Share your conn.php file

Comment: You really don't give us enough to go on here.  We need some more of your program flow.

Comment: replace all include() with require() and you'll generate a fatal error on fail to include => easier to track down failing paths.

Comment: There is no built in **connect()** function in PHP, maybe you mean `mysql_connect()` ? which is deprecated anyway ...

Comment: @Hamza, it is a custom connect in DB.php

Comment: "Connect" !== "ConnectToDB", no?

Comment: my apologies ring0, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I though of a solution by using an absolute path, so in `conn.php` change `include_once ("mods/DB.php");` to: `include_once('C:\\htdocs\\mods\\DB.PHP');`.

[This may also be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344419/how-do-i-set-an-absolute-include-path-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

In your situation i would make one file which would contain define('MOD_PATH', 'mods/'); and then used MOD_PATH everywhere, where the 'conn.php' appears, it would be wiser that way, because, then you wouldn't need to put mods in every file, but in one... Well, that's my opinion from what i would start...