# Text after include ''; skipped

Tags: php, include

I want to include a php file using `include '';`. But for some reason nothing after the include statement appears.

Here is the include statement:

```
<td height="50">
    <?php include 'http://grizeldi.host-ed.me/Resources/components/menubar.php'; ?>
</td>
```

Everything after this is not displayed on the webpage when I open it (including ).

My menubar.php file:

```
<?php echo "
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='http://grizeldi.host-ed.me'><span>Domov</span></a></li>
        <!--<li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Izdelki</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=grizeldi'><span>Android aplikacije</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>gGears</span></a></li>
                    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Še kej</span></a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>-->
        <!--<li><a href='#'><span>O meni</span></a></li>-->
        <li><a href='/igre'><span>Igre</span></a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#kontakt'><span>Kontakt</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div> "; ?>
```

You can check the malformed output here: http://grizeldi.host-ed.me/igre/page_template.php

Comment: Hey check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/344464/3448527

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use URL's to include files, pass a string relative to the caller page location, such as

```
<?php
   include 'Resources/components/menubar.php';
?>
```

A quote from the PHP.net website about includes talking about the location.

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing.

Also I suggest you turn all of your URL's to lowercase since it will help prevent issues in the future.

For including folders that are up a directory, you will want to use the `../` directory path to mean "parent directory". You may also use `./` to fetch the current directory, but fetching the current directory isn't really needed with the PHP `include()` function.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: I thought of that but problem is that the resources folder is in the folder one level up than the file which doesn't work...

Comment: I added this to the answer, use the "../" directory to go up a single directory. You can use this multiple times.