# How to block includes from specific directories PHP

Tags: php, include, php-ini

### Problem

Imagine I have the following directory structure:

```
root
| 123
| | index.php
| | abc
| | | file.php
| 456
| | another_file.php
```

How can I configure PHP so that `index.php` can include `file.php` but not `another_file.php`?

In other words, `include("abc/file.php")` should work, but `include("../456/another_file.php")` shouldn't.

### Reason

The reason that I need to do this is because on my web server, I have two virtualhosts on the same filesystem, and these are for two different users. Each user should be able to include files that live in their own folder, but they shouldn't be able to include files from outside of it.

Each virtualhost has its own php.ini file (courtesy of [suPHP](https://www.suphp.org/Home.html)).

### Research / Attempts

I have tried using the `include_path` php.ini setting (see: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path), but have got nowhere. I have also researched this topic extensively on StackOverflow, but to no avail - i.e. [How do I set an absolute include path in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344419/how-do-i-set-an-absolute-include-path-in-php) doesn't help, because I don't want this to be optional or a piece of code that needs to be appended to files.

Comment: The best fix would be to prevent it at OS level. You even use suPHP, a module created exactly for that. Otherwise, you'll soon learn that they're many other ways to read files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have two folder `123` and `456` ,and they just can open their folder's file 
You can try this :

create the .user.ini in folder `123` and `456`
 add  directive `open_basedir=./:/tmp/:/usr/local/php/`
 to  file [.usr.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)

```
 root
    | 123
    | | .user.ini
    | | index.php
    | | abc
    | | | file.php
    | 456
    | | .user.ini
    | | another_file.php
```

and

```
touch  ./root/123/.user.ini
echo 'open_basedir=./:/tmp/:/usr/local/php/' > ./root/123/.user.ini
touch  ./root/456/.user.ini
echo 'open_basedir=./:/tmp/:/usr/local/php/' > ./root/456/.user.ini
```

** Then restart the php-fpm**

the folder  `./` is  `/root/123/`

the  folder `/usr/local/php/` is your php folder which you **must include**,it should depend on where you install the php, in my computer ,it is `/usr/local/php/`
and the `tmp` folder may save som tmp file.

you can use the `:` to divide different  Folder

Comment: Thanks so much! I hadn't checked out `open_basedir` and it does exactly what I want.