# how to select hierarchical categories in a dropdown php oop way?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to create a function that can list hierarchical categories in a dropdown.
Using orient objected

$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

Database :
cat_id  cat_name parent_id seo_url

I list them as normal categories this way.

```
                      <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
                       if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
                        if($result->num_rows > 0){
                            while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
                            echo "<option value=".htmlspecialchars($row[cat_id]).">".htmlspecialchars($row[cat_name])."</option>";
                            }
                        // Free result set
                         $result->free();
                        } else{
                            echo "No records matching your query were found.";
                            }
                        } else{
                            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $conn->error;
                        }

                        // Close connection
                        $conn->close();
                      ?>
```

But this is not what I want.

What I want is (main category on the top and all sub categories belong to it list under it.

```
main category
-Sub Category 
main category
-Sub Category
```

and this is the function I create

```
function categoryTree($parent_id = 0, $sub_mark = ''){
    global $conn;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = $parent_id";
                       if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
                        if($result->num_rows > 0){
                            while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
                                        echo '<option value="'.$row['cat_id'].'">'.$sub_mark.$row['cat_name'].'</option>';
            categoryTree($row['cat_id'], $sub_mark.'---');
                            }
                        // Free result set
                         $result->free();
                        } else{
                            echo "No records matching your query were found.";
                            }
                        } else{
                            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $conn->error;
                        }

                        // Close connection
                        $conn->close();
    }
```

But fucntion return empty. 
**EDIT**
I passed conn to variables and pasted codes here, fucntion returns empty no dropdown box.
**Edit 2 :**
I changed my query type and connection type, I dont want to use global conn in my function, but cant list without using global $conn;.
how can I list without using global $conn; ?

Comment: `$conn` is out of scope. If you enabled PHP errors you'd see the error

Comment: to use `num_rows` with `->prepare` you must use [store_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php)

Comment: I am getting this error now  `Notice: Undefined variable: conn in` how to solve it ?@IsThisJavascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Made it with prepare statments thanks for the help.
here is the solution

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT cat_id, cat_name, seo_url FROM categories WHERE parent_id = ?");
    function list_categories($stmt, $parent_id = 0){
    $stmt->reset();
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $parent_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($cat_id, $cat_name, $seo_url);
    $cats = array();
    while($stmt->fetch()) $cats[] = array('cat_id' => $cat_id, 'cat_name' => $cat_name, 'seo_url' => $seo_url);

    foreach($cats as $row) {
        echo'<ul>';
            echo'<li><a href="'.htmlspecialchars($row['cat_id']).'-'. htmlspecialchars($row['seo_url']).'">'. htmlspecialchars($row['cat_name']).'</a>';
            list_categories($stmt, htmlspecialchars($row['cat_id']));
            echo'</li>';
        echo'</ul>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to see you got your issue resolved, please mark this as answered so the thread can be closed

Answer (score 0):

**Notice: Undefined variable: conn in** means Including the file outside the class connect Db won't work.

For a test, if you want to sure your PHP file can connect to the database first run **var_dump($conn)** in your PHP file.

if you have an output it means that the connection to the database works for you.Otherwise, you must correct it

your file connection must somethinging like this

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password","dbName");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

and then you must include that file in the PHP file ((*It means any file
which needs to be connected to the database*))

```
include 'yourPatch/con.php';
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer @pedram shabani I changed `$con = mysqli_connect `  to `$conn` and changed ny sql querry too, but My problem is using global $conn now, why I cant list categories without using $conn. which is I dont want to use global $db connection.

Comment: If you dont want to use global  $conn you have to use $conn Locally.((Any file that changes the database data. Must be connected to the database))

Comment: Function added to functions.php and calling function in cats.php which is db file included in cats.php `require_once 'dbconnect.php';
require_once 'inc/functions.php';` stil doesnt work when I remove global $conn, function returns empty.

Comment: Use absolute patch..plz reading this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344419/how-do-i-set-an-absolute-include-path-in-php